# Convert \n in a clear space

Tags: php, function

i have a problem with a function in php i want to convert all the "\n" in a clear space, i've tried with this, but it doesn't work

```
function clean($text) {
    if ($text === null) return null;
    if (strstr($text, "\xa7") || strstr($text, "&")) {
        $text = preg_replace("/(?i)(\x{00a7}|&)[0-9A-FK-OR]/u", "", $text);
    }
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    if (strstr($text, "\n")) {
        $text = preg_replace("\n", "", $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

This is wat i want remove[image]

The site: [click here](http://www.svapomc.com/ban/bans.php)

Comment: Does `$text` contain HTML?

Comment: I don't know where i can see it? because this is a site for a ban list so i doesn't have created this. But problably not

Comment: add some examples..

Comment: Do you literally have `\n` ? If yes do `$text = str_replace("\n", " ", $text);`

Comment: i've updated the question. matiaslauriti it doesn't work

Comment: ok i've gived the site too

Comment: Ok thank you at all i've resolved this i've forget to add another \ to if (strstr($text, "\n")) {

Comment: Bear in mind that `strstr` will only find the first occurrence of "\n", not sure why `str_replace` wasn't working for you though (which finds all the occurrences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally have "\n" in your text, which appears to be the case from your screenshots, then do the following:

`$text = str_replace("\\n", '', $text);`

`\n` is a special character in PHP that creates new lines, so we need to add the escape character `\` in front of it in order to remove *text* instances of "\n".

Comment: Or if they are inside single-quotes, they aren't evaluated as special characters, and you don't have to escape it. Live example: https://3v4l.org/O96XD and manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` seems to work better this way:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\n/',"",$text);
```

Single quotes enforce no substitution when sending your pattern to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work, i don't know why i've tried this too.

Comment: Can you tell us what error messages you're getting (if any)? How are you checking that it's working? Try to `echo $text` somewhere if you're not already, so you can see whether the output is what you expected.

Comment: where i put this?